# How to load model architecture and model weights from saved_model.pb file?

Tags: python, keras

I have a tensorflow model saved with tf.saved_model.save . It generates a directory where saved_model.pb file is saved . I can infer with inputs like this

```
model_loaded=tf.saved_model.load(model_directory)

infer = model_loaded.signatures["serving_default"]

infer(inputs)
```

`model_directory` holds these folders and files `assets`,`saved_model.pb`,`variables` .

I can also list the attributes of `model_loaded` object using

```
print(dir(model_loaded))
```

And the output is :

```
['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_add_trackable_child', '_add_variable_with_custom_getter', '_checkpoint_dependencies', '_default_save_signature', '_deferred_dependencies', '_delete_tracking', '_deserialization_dependencies', '_deserialize_from_proto', '_export_to_saved_model_graph', '_gather_saveables_for_checkpoint', '_get_legacy_saved_model_children', '_handle_deferred_dependencies', '_list_extra_dependencies_for_serialization', '_list_functions_for_serialization', '_lookup_dependency', '_map_resources', '_maybe_initialize_trackable', '_name_based_attribute_restore', '_name_based_restores', '_no_dependency', '_object_identifier', '_preload_simple_restoration', '_restore_from_checkpoint_position', '_restore_from_tensors', '_self_name_based_restores', '_self_saveable_object_factories', '_self_setattr_tracking', '_self_unconditional_checkpoint_dependencies', '_self_unconditional_deferred_dependencies', '_self_unconditional_dependency_names', '_self_update_uid', '_serialize_to_proto', '_serialize_to_tensors', '_setattr_tracking', '_single_restoration_from_checkpoint_position', '_tf_api_names', '_tf_api_names_v1', '_track_trackable', '_trackable_children', '_unconditional_checkpoint_dependencies', '_unconditional_dependency_names', '_update_uid', 'call_and_return_all_conditional_losses', 'graph_debug_info', 'keras_api', 'layer-0', 'layer-1', 'layer-10', 'layer-11', 'layer-12', 'layer-13', 'layer-14', 'layer-15', 'layer-2', 'layer-3', 'layer-4', 'layer-5', 'layer-6', 'layer-7', 'layer-8', 'layer-9', 'layer_with_weights-0', 'layer_with_weights-1', 'layer_with_weights-2', 'layer_with_weights-3', 'layer_with_weights-4', 'layer_with_weights-5', 'optimizer', 'regularization_losses', 'signatures', 'tensorflow_git_version', 'tensorflow_version', 'trainable_variables', 'variables']
```

Is there any way I could load model architecture object and model weights(possibly an object which could show the model architecture like this `model.summary()`) .

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You can already call `.summary()` on your loaded model.

Comment: @ClaudiaR tf.saved_model.load() doesn't create typical tf model object . I had to get 'serving_default' attribute to make inference . Check this document https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#creating_a_savedmodel_from_keras . So you cant do model.summary(),model.predict() and staffs like this .

Comment: Ah, yes I see, my bad. I posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

You saved it with tensorflow alone, but, if you have the opportunity, you could load it back using keras.

From the TensorFlow [Docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/load):

> Keras models are trackable, so they can be saved to SavedModel. The
> object returned by `tf.saved_model.load` is not a Keras object (i.e.
> doesn't have `.fit`, `.predict`, etc. methods). A few attributes and
> functions are still available: `.variables`, `.trainable_variables` and
> .`__call__`.
>
> Use `tf.keras.models.load_model` to restore the Keras model.

At this point you should get all your desired extra keras functions.